# C++ token types

Tags: c++, token, language-lawyer

I am assuming that C++ token types (as per `2.7 Tokens [lex.token]`) do not form an intersecting sets (i.e. `int` is considered to belong only to the `keyword` token type and not both `keyword` and `identifier` token types). Taking that into account the following question arises.

C++11 quote:

> 2.2 Phases of translation [lex.phases]
>
> 7 White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. (2.7). The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

So, the syntactic and semantic analysis of the C++ text is preformed AFTER the text is spilt into tokens.

Another C++11 quote:

> 2.7 Tokens [lex.token]
>
> token:
> identiﬁer
> keyword
> literal
> operator
> punctuator

Nowhere in the standard I have found the definition for the `operator` and `punctuator` grammar non-terminals. Anyway, according to the `2.12 Keywords` and `2.13 Operators and punctuators` the token `new` can be either a `keyword` or an `operator` token. How could C++ compiler can possibly determine the type of the `new` token BEFORE performing syntactic and semantic analysis of the code?

Comment: Why would you assume that token types do not form intersecting sets, when the standard shows the `new` and `delete` tokens showing up in multiple sets?

Comment: @Sneftel If we assume intersecting sets, then according to my quote of 2.2 `new` will never make it into both `keyword` AND `operator` (only `keyword`), so what's the point of making the sets intersecting?

Comment: Operators and punctuators are defined in 2.13 (although it doesn't specify which are operators and which are punctuators). I think the answer to the question is simply "it can't", but I'm not a compiler expert.

Comment: @Mike The answer "it can't" would mean the compiler wouldn't be able to spilt the code into tokens if the code contains the word `new` and as such most C++ programs would not be possible to compile at all. :) 2.13 defines the grammar for `preprocessing-op-or-punc`, not `operator` and `punctuator`.

Comment: @PowerGamer The compiler is not required to categorize tokens at that stage (or ever, really). The categories are just to streamline description within the Standard. Because `new` is a keyword, and can be an operator, it must be in both groups.

Comment: @PowerGamer: Of course it can split the code into tokens. It just can't determine the kind of token without contextual analysis, making the language more complex to compile than one with a context-free grammar.

Comment: @PowerGamer: "2.13 defines the grammar for `preprocessing-op-or-punc`, not `operator` and `punctuator`" - indeed, as I said, it neglects to specify which are punctuators and which are operators. But that's where they're (collectively) defined.

Comment: @Sneftel Isn't compiler supposed to act "as if" according to the standard description? Also, are you implying that for ex., in the following context `new` is a keyword but not an operator: `void* operator new (){return nullptr;}`?

Comment: @PowerGamer Not sure what you're getting at. The standard does not attach any importance to token categories before the translation phase, so the compiler has no need to worry about those categories. Think of them like footnotes in the Standard: They add context, not rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` and `delete` are the overloadable operators whose name is formed of a single token.

The differences between the productions *preprocessing-op-or-punc* (**[lex.operators]**/1) and *operator* (**[over.oper]**/1) are the removal of the punctuators and preprocessing operators `{ } [ ] # ## ( ) ; : ...`, the digraph alternate tokens `<: :>` etc., the non-overloadable operators `. .* :: ?`, the lexical keyword alternate tokens `and and_eq` etc., and the addition of the multitoken operators `new[]`, `delete[]`, `()`, and `[]`. `new`, `delete`, `new[]` and `delete[]` are included in *operator* so that their *operator-function-id*s (`operator new` etc.) can follow the rules of other overloadable operators without having to duplicate language, keep it updated, and invent a new production (*dynamic-function-id*?) to occur everywhere *operator-function-id* occurs. Note that non-overloadable operators whose name has the lexical form of an identifier (`sizeof`, `typeid`, etc.) are not included in *operator*, and thus nor in *preprocessing-op-or-punc*.

While this introduces an ambiguity between the *identifier* and *preprocessing-op-or-punc* productions, this does not affect phase 3 translation in any way. For phase 7, where the ambiguity is between *keyword* and *operator*, this is again not a problem, since the *operator* production and others that include the tokens `new` and `delete` e.g. *new-expression* (**[expr.new]**) do not reference the *keyword* or *operator* productions but instead contain the relevant tokens directly.

Comment: `2.12 Keywords [lex.key], 1)` states that `new` and some others are `unconditionally treated as keywords in phase 7`. Yet, you assume that it can also be treated as `operator` (which already is a contradiction in the standard IMO) and also imply that `new` can't be treated as `identifier` during phase 7 (if you accept that `new` is both `keyword` and `operator` token then you must accept that it also is `identifier` token at the same time).

Comment: If `new` and `delete` are parsed as *operator* s as opposed to *identifier* s then [lex.key]/1 doesn't apply (it can only move tokens from the production *identifier* to *keyword*, not from the production *operator*). As discussed in [gram], the grammar is not intended to be exact, so it's fine for it to contain ambiguities as long as they are resolved at a later stage of translation or of parsing.

Comment: Lets talk about a `token` at phase 7 BEFORE syntactic and semantic analysis. Are the `token` types intersecting or not? I.e. is `new` treated as: 1) `identifier` AND `keyword` AND `operator` at the same time or as 2) ONE OF (`identifier`, `keyword`, `operator`) but we don't know which one yet.

Comment: It's up to you how you regard an ambiguous parse; is `A * B;` 1) *expression-statement* AND *simple-declaration* or 2) ONE OF (*expression-statement*, *simple-declaration*)? A C++ compiler has to be able to cope with ambiguity at the syntactic level.